# 404 on Homepage magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

When I upgraded from 2.2.0 to 2.2.2

I having an issue with 404 on the homepage.

every setting in `stores/configurations/general/web/default pages` seems to be ok, even checked the **core_config_data** table which also seems to be alright.

I have deleted all modules/themes to avoid conflicts

**cache** cleared

**var** folder deleted

i have used

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

couple of times already

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have Varnish on top of Magento?

Comment: nope just regular caching

Answer (score 6):

You can check DB table `url_rewrite` and found row cotains request_path='' (empty).It helped me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21299

I hope it helps who are getting this issue.